# Raycasting unknown error

Tags: c#, vector, unity-game-engine, detection, raycasting

I have this problem which I have been trying to figure out for quite some time already. The code I have below is almost complete. I just need to add this additional feature it should work how I want it to work.

So what I want to implement into the code is the make alertedLock false when !withinRange.
But for some reason no matter how i do it. It doesnt work. Because the problem i have is that, when i implement some kind of code to do that, everything goes back to normal.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
The script should be doing this:

1. If player !withinRange && !withinAngle of enemy then, enemy.color.blue;
2. If player !withinRange &&  withinAngle of enemy then, enemy.color.blue;
3. If player  withinRange && !withinAngle of enemy then, enemy.color.red;
4. If player  withinRange && withinAngle of enemy then, enemy.color.green;
5. If player  withinRange && touchRestrictedRaycast of enemy then, enemy.color.magenta (forever) unless !withinRange && !withinAnge

The problem is 5. I dont know how to code 5.
**Edit**
When i tried to code it outside the forloop , that is,

```
if (alertedLock && !withinRange) {

    alertedLock = false;        

}
```

Does doesnt solve the problem. It returns the solution to where alertedLock is always false
Even when i try to apply it inside the for loop. Such like,

```
if(withinRange) {
        // Inside
        if(alertedLock) {
            gameObject.renderer.material.color = Color.magenta;
        }
        if(!alertedLock) {
            if(enemyAngleTLUP || enemyAngleTLLEFT) {
                alertedLock = true;
            }
            if(withinAngle) {
                gameObject.renderer.material.color = Color.green;
            }
            if(!withinAngle) {
                gameObject.renderer.material.color = Color.red;
            }

        }

}
if (!withinRange){
        if(alteredLock) {
                alertedLock = false;
        }
}
```

There is a problem when i do this, its because once it detects the first raycast detection. It ignores the rest, and so it has this color state problem.
I found out this problem on my earlier questions, here:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/90329/raycast-flashing-problem

**Edit**
alertedLock is just a bool which determines when the player has touched the restricted raycast. Due to the fact the player can only kill the enemy from a certain range and angle (withinRange && withinAngle). This is why we have alertedLock.

However, when alertedLock is true. It can only be turned off when the player isnt within the kill range of the enemy (!withinRange)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Script_v2 : MonoBehaviour {

// Player Properties
private GameObject player;
public Vector3 playerSize;
private Vector3 playerTransform;
public Vector3 playerTransformTL;
public Vector3 playerTransformTR;
public Vector3 playerTransformBL;
public Vector3 playerTransformBR;

private Vector3 newPlayerTransformTL;
private Vector3 newPlayerTransformTR;

private Vector3[] playerRaycastPoints;


// Enemy Properties
private Vector3 enemyTransformTL;
private Vector3 enemyTransformTR;
private Vector3 enemyTransformBL;
private Vector3 enemyTransformBR;

public float distance;
public Vector3 enemySize;

// Detection Alerts
public bool outOfVision;
public bool alerted;
public bool alertedLock;

public bool withinRange;
public bool withinAngle;

public bool dead;

Ray ray;
RaycastHit hit;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    playerRaycastPoints = new Vector3[4];

    distance = 3f;
    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player");


}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    enemyTransformTL = new Vector3 (transform.position.x - 0.5f, transform.position.y + 0.5f, transform.position.z);
    enemyTransformTR = new Vector3 (transform.position.x + 0.5f, transform.position.y + 0.5f, transform.position.z);


    enemyTransform_TL_TR ();
    Reference_Player_Transform_Points ();
    Player_Transform_Points_Detection ();

    Debug.Log (alerted + " " + alertedLock);

}

void OnDrawGizmos() {
    Gizmos.color = Color.blue;
    Gizmos.DrawWireSphere (new Vector3(transform.position.x - 0.5f, transform.position.y + 0.5f, transform.position.z), distance);
    //Gizmos.DrawWireSphere (new Vector3(transform.position.x + 0.5f, transform.position.y + 0.5f, transform.position.z), distance);
}

public void enemyTransform_TL_TR() {

    if (alertedLock && !withinRange) {

        alertedLock = false;        

    }
    if (!alertedLock) {
        gameObject.renderer.material.color = Color.blue;
    }



    for (int i = 0; i < playerRaycastPoints.Length; i++) {

        double enemyAngleTL = Mathf.Atan2(playerRaycastPoints[i].y - ( transform.position.y + 0.5f ),
                                          playerRaycastPoints[i].x - ( transform.position.x - 0.5f )) * 180f / 3.14159265f;
        //Debug.Log (enemyAngleTL);
        double enemyAngleTR = Mathf.Atan2 (playerRaycastPoints[i].y - (transform.position.y + 0.5f),
                                           playerRaycastPoints[i].x - (transform.position.x + 0.5f)) * 180f / 3.14159265f;

        Vector3 directionTL = (playerRaycastPoints[i] - enemyTransformTL).normalized;
        Ray rayTL = new Ray(enemyTransformTL, directionTL);
        RaycastHit hitTL;
        Vector3 directionTR = (playerRaycastPoints[i] - enemyTransformTR).normalized;
        Ray rayTR = new Ray (enemyTransformTR, directionTR);
        RaycastHit hitTR;

        withinRange = Physics.Raycast (rayTL, out hitTL, distance);
        withinAngle = enemyAngleTL > 90 && enemyAngleTL < 180;

        RaycastHit hitTPUP;
        RaycastHit hitTPLEFT;
        bool enemyAngleTLUP = Physics.Raycast(enemyTransformTL, Vector3.up, out hitTPUP, distance);
        bool enemyAngleTLLEFT = Physics.Raycast(enemyTransformTL, Vector3.left, out hitTPLEFT, distance);


        Debug.DrawRay(enemyTransformTL, Vector3.up * distance);
        Debug.DrawRay(enemyTransformTL, Vector3.left * distance);


        if(withinRange) {
            // Inside
            if(alertedLock) {
                gameObject.renderer.material.color = Color.magenta;
            }
            if(!alertedLock) {
                if(enemyAngleTLUP || enemyAngleTLLEFT) {
                    alertedLock = true;
                }
                if(withinAngle) {
                    gameObject.renderer.material.color = Color.green;
                }
                if(!withinAngle) {
                    gameObject.renderer.material.color = Color.red;
                }

            }

        }




    }



}

private void Reference_Player_Transform_Points() {

    playerSize = player.transform.localScale;

    playerTransformTL = new Vector3(player.transform.position.x - (playerSize.x / 2),
                                    player.transform.position.y + playerSize.y  / 2,
                                    player.transform.position.z);
    playerTransformTR = new Vector3(player.transform.position.x + (playerSize.x / 2),
                                    player.transform.position.y + playerSize.y  / 2,
                                    player.transform.position.z);
    playerTransformBL = new Vector3(player.transform.position.x - (playerSize.x / 2),
                                    player.transform.position.y - playerSize.y  / 2,
                                    player.transform.position.z);
    playerTransformBR = new Vector3(player.transform.position.x + (playerSize.x / 2),
                                    player.transform.position.y - playerSize.y  / 2,
                                    player.transform.position.z);

    playerRaycastPoints [0] = playerTransformTL;
    playerRaycastPoints [1] = playerTransformTR;
    playerRaycastPoints [2] = playerTransformBL;
    playerRaycastPoints [3] = playerTransformBR;

    /*
        Debug.Log (playerTransformTL);
        Debug.Log (playerTransformTR);
        Debug.Log (playerTransformBL);
        Debug.Log (playerTransformBR);
    */
}

private void Player_Transform_Points_Detection() {
    float eTLpTL = Vector3.Distance (enemyTransformTL, playerTransformTL);
    float eTLpTR = Vector3.Distance (enemyTransformTL, playerTransformTR);
    float eTLpBL = Vector3.Distance (enemyTransformTL, playerTransformBL);
    float eTLpBR = Vector3.Distance (enemyTransformTL, playerTransformBR);

    float eTRpTL = Vector3.Distance (enemyTransformTR, playerTransformTL);
    float eTRpTR = Vector3.Distance (enemyTransformTR, playerTransformTR);
    float eTRpBL = Vector3.Distance (enemyTransformTR, playerTransformBL);
    float eTRpBR = Vector3.Distance (enemyTransformTR, playerTransformBR);


    float eTLMin = Mathf.Min (eTLpTL, eTLpTR, eTLpBL, eTLpBR);

    if (eTLMin == eTLpTL) {
        newPlayerTransformTL = playerTransformTL;
        // Debug.Log("eTLpTL");     
    }
    else if(eTLMin == eTLpTR) {
        newPlayerTransformTL = playerTransformTR;
        // Debug.Log("eTLpTR");
    }
    else if(eTLMin == eTLpBL) {
        newPlayerTransformTL = playerTransformBL;
        // Debug.Log("eTLpBL");
    }
    else if(eTLMin == eTLpBR) {
        newPlayerTransformTL = playerTransformBR;
        // Debug.Log("eTLpBR");
    }

    float eTRMin = Mathf.Min (eTRpTL, eTRpTR, eTRpBL, eTRpBR);

    if(eTRMin == eTRpTL) {
        newPlayerTransformTR = playerTransformTL;
        // Debug.Log("eTRpTL");
    }
    else if(eTRMin == eTRpTR) {
        newPlayerTransformTR = playerTransformTR;
        // Debug.Log("eTRpTR");
    }
    else if(eTRMin == eTRpBL) {
        newPlayerTransformTR = playerTransformBL;
        // Debug.Log("eTRpBL");
    }
    else if(eTRMin == eTRpBR) {
        newPlayerTransformTR = playerTransformBR;
        // Debug.Log("eTRpBR");
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Your description of the problem is very vague. Can you try to be more specific? Really, you should identify a small piece of your code that is giving you problems. No one will want to read through this gigantic block of code to try to figure out what one part you might be trying to get help with.

Comment: The question has been edited